# Veins(Omnet++) WAVE packet priority mapping to EDCA(Enhanced Distributed Channel Access)

Tags: omnet++, wave, qos, veins

When creating **WaveShortMessage** or **(wsm)** in **Veins**, there is a priority field that needs to be specified for each packet. The priority levels that can be used are 0-3. Also based on [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6765173) paper **WAVE** uses EDCA as MAC layer protocol. EDCA has four different Access Categories (AC) or queues. These queues are used to prioritize outgoing packets. My questions are:

1. In **WSM**, does 0 have the highest priority or lowest priority?
2. How does **WSM** packet priorities map to **EDCA** access categories? Or does it map at all? If not, then is there any way in Veins, where I could assign packets to specific access category in EDCA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Veins 4a2, assignment of packets from upper layers to EDCA queues is done in the MAC's [handleUpperMsg](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc#L249) function, which calls [mapPriority](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc#L554). This function performs the following straightforward assignment:

```
case 0: return AC_BK;
case 1: return AC_BE;
case 2: return AC_VI;
case 3: return AC_VO;
```